# How to set stack size with m68k-uclinux-gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, stack, uclinux

Does anyone know what the CLI options are to set the stack size for the m68K gcc cross compiler?

I tried using -Wl,-stack_size,0x0000f000 in my CFLAGS, but running m68k-uclinux-flthdr seems to indicate it's still set to 0x1000?

```
[fred@localhost q4cgi]$ m68k-uclinux-flthdr a
a
    Magic:        bFLT
    Rev:          4
    Build Date:   Sat Apr  7 10:23:44 2012
    Entry:        0x44
    Data Start:   0xcec0
    Data End:     0xe5f4
    BSS End:      0x107f0
    Stack Size:   0x1000
    Reloc Start:  0xe5f4
    Reloc Count:  0x5c1
    Flags:        0x1 ( Load-to-Ram )
```

Answer (score 0):

use -s option  for e.g.  --->

```
m68k-uclinux-flthdr -s 16000
```

above command will change stack size to 16 kb(approx.)

similarly you can have any size